# I want to wrap my texts in fixed height container, the problem is in case of long text, the text is cutting

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

```
       Flexible(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                email.bodyPreview,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color:
                    AppColors.primaryText.withOpacity(bodyOpacity),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    letterSpacing: 0.18,),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

The widget tree is Container(height: 130) -> Column -> Flexible -> Container -> Text.
I have tried with softwrap attribute but nothing much happening.

Comment: Did you try using Expanded?

Comment: Yes @AR getting same behaviour

Comment: change container height use mediaQuery instead of height = 130

Comment: @AR i think he is setting the height intentionally to the fixed height so all the elements (in a list) will look the same.

Comment: What is your desired result ? To fit text inside given width/height or to show the ellipsis at the end ?

Comment: @NaveenAvidi If text is larger then it should show ellipsis instead of rendering another line. In the above screenshot, after ----- this line another line is rendering it should not, the line should be end in --- with ellipsis

Comment: I tested you code its working fine ! May be your string contains new line character (\n) !

Comment: @NaveenAvidi What's your parent widget height? And have you tried with long text which will have 10 to 20 lines

Comment: In the above image I can only see a flexible-container-text ! But you didint posted your parent widget like column or listview or something else !

Comment: @NaveenAvidi I have mentioned in description for widget tree Container(height: 130) -> Column -> Flexible -> Container -> Text.

Comment: Is container (130 ) is the root widget ?

Comment: Yes @NaveenAvidi

Comment: Everything fine by your conversation ! You can check my answer below !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your `Text` inside `SingleChildScrollView` and wrap it in `Expanded`. That will make the text scrollable if it is too long. Like this

```
Expanded(
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Text("YOUR TEXT")
          )
   );
```

Comment: But I don't want the text to be scrolled

Comment: @ShaktiS.P.Swain Then I think your code contradict itself. First you give it a fixed height of 130 and at the same time want it to be Flexible and not scroll. Do you want the cutted text to be gone from the view or want to show the whole text?

Comment: The text should be gone from the view

Comment: Then I think you should use maxLines property of Text. In your case, try setting maxLines in accordance with your container's height. The portion of the text that's over maxlines will be treated according to overflow policy

Answer (score 0):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding:EdgeInsets.all(15),
    height:130,
    width:double.infinity,
    child:Column(
      mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
      child: Container(
        child: LimitedBox(
          maxHeight:200,
          child: Text('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
          +'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'+
                    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color:Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          letterSpacing: 0.18,),),
        ),
      ),
    ),
      ],
    )
    );
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Here the text will wrap only in one line. But I want multilines

Comment: I update my answer with LimitedBox. Replace maxiHeight with your required height !